# Error when invoking procedure from http

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters, worklight-server

I'm trying to invoke the adapter "PushAdapter" from the example project Module_07_04_nativeAPIForiOSPush from my local Worklight Studio (version 6 with fix pack 1) and getting the below error in the browser:

```
/*-secure-
{"errors":["I O: Unexpected character 'd' on line 1, 
column 27"],"isSuccessful":false,"warnings":[],"info":[]}*/
```

The URL I'm using is:

http://192.168.1.106:10080/Module_07_04_nativeAPIForiOSPush/invoke?adapter=PushAdapter&procedure=submitNotification&parameters=['worklight,'doesitwork']

I looked in the local Worklight server messages.log and it's throwing this error:

```
[10/2/13 9:34:11:179 EDT] 0000078f 
om.worklight.integration.services.impl.DataAccessServiceImpl E FWLSE0013E: Cannot invoke 
procedure PushAdapter/submitNotification [project Module_07_04_nativeAPIForiOSPush]
java.io.IOException: Unexpected character 'd' on line 1, column 27
at com.ibm.json.java.internal.Tokenizer.next(Tokenizer.java:129)
at com.ibm.json.java.internal.Parser.parseValue(Parser.java:208)
at com.ibm.json.java.internal.Parser.parseArray(Parser.java:162)
at com.ibm.json.java.internal.Parser.parseValue(Parser.java:230)
...
```

There are a few other posts indicating similar issues parsing the Json objects/arrays.  So, I changed the return value to only return an empty object:

```
return {};
```

But, still same error.  Running it via the Worklight Studio (Run As...|Invoke Worklight Procedure) displays:

```
{
   "isSuccessful": true
}
```

I'm intending to use this approach (GET request from an external app to the Worklight server) to run notifications push, but, if a basic GET request doesn't work, I'll have to look for another approach.

Question 1:  Is this the correct Http GET format?
Question 2:  For notifications push scheduling, is this a typical approach?

Comment: Is that a typo, or is ['worklight,'doesitwork'] missing a quote after worklight?

Comment: Wow, you're right!  Another pair of eyes does the trick, thank you!  It's working.

Comment: @DavidDhuyveter, you should write that as an answer so that DavidW will mark it and we could "close" this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a typo in the URL.  Missing a quote after worklight.